# Flutter, Web, navigation 2.0 browser back button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

I found about 10 project of the Navigation 2.0 Flutter Web Sample project through a hard searching.

And it seems that all web components change only on one screen, and no new screens appear. They are internally logically stacked, but they don't look like a browser stack. I've seen every time that the back button doesn't work like a normal website.

Is this not possible in Navigation 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle back button click event, you need to use  `onPopPage` of `Navigator` on your `RouterDelegate`.

It will be like

```dart
 onPopPage: (route, result) {
        if (!route.didPop(result)) {
          return false;
        }
        notifier.changeScreen(pageName: null); //home
        notifyListeners();
        return true;
      },
```

Here is my [project](https://github.com/yeasin50/Lisa-Fischer/blob/master/lib/routes/route.routerDelegate.dart) and [practices](https://github.com/yeasin50/Dart_-Flutter_Advanced/tree/master/lib/navigator2) that will help you.

Comment: Browser back button not causing a pop for me so this doesn't get called. `WidgetsBindingObserver.didPushRoute` executes when the browser back is pressed. Not sure if we can do anything useful in that or not.